# How to use AngularJS to display an json API the key is two words?

Tags: angularjs, json

I met a problem which is using AngularJS to display a json file which the key contains two words like this:

```
items: [
{
period: "2017-05-01",
total: 3901,
eloisa moreira: 142,
william morales: 0,
lenilda carvalho: 0,
anamaris gonzalez: 0,
juliana ambroise: 1,
ana luiza theriault: 622,
teresa daveiga: 0
}]
```

I use:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="data in data.items">
                <td>{{data.period}}</td>
                <td>{{data.total}}</td> 
                <!--<td>{{data.eloisa moreira}}</td> -->                  
 </tr>
```

The first two values are displayed fine, but the third one: {{data.eloisa moreira}} give me error: 
angular.js:13708 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'moreira' is an unexpected token at column 13 of the expression [data.eloisa moreira] starting at [moreira].
Any one how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are intended to show all fields of the object, you can use a inner `ng-repeat` with `(key, value)` to avoid redundant code and hardcoding properties of object.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in data.items">
  <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      items: [{
        "period": "2017-05-01",
        "total": 3901,
        "eloisa moreira": 142,
        "william morales": 0,
        "lenilda carvalho": 0,
        "anamaris gonzalez": 0,
        "juliana ambroise": 1,
        "ana luiza theriault": 622,
        "teresa daveiga": 0
      }]
    };
  });
```

```css
.solid {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table class="solid">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in data.items">
      <!--<td>{{data.period}}</td>
      <td>{{data.total}}</td>
      <td>{{data.eloisa moreira}}</td> -->
      <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It exactly what I need!

Answer (score 2):

The key in the JSON Object contains a space, so you can't use the dot-operator shortcut to index into the object. You should be able to use the traditional index approach:

`<td>{{data['eloisa moreira']}}</td>`

Comment: Sure thing. And just to clarify, this isn't an AngularJS specific issue, it's related to core JavaScript.